# Will users be turned off by a long all-caps URL?

Tags: client-relations, barcodes

I'm designing a QR code to link to a long URL (beyond my control). I noticed that I can convert all the letters in the URL to uppercase, allowing me to take advantage of QR codes' alphanumeric mode to make the code smaller. Testing indicates that scanners can still read the code and still provide a button to open the code in a browser.

However, I'm concerned that the long string of all-caps text may intimidate users. Is this fear justified?

Comment: Are you showing the all-caps URL somewhere? If it's automatically processed by the browser, I believe all browsers convert the domain name itself to lowercase. Like `GOOGLE.COM` will become `google.com`. But `FOO.BAR/TEST` will be `foo.bar/TEST`.

Comment: Would the users *ever* see the actual URL anywhere but a browser address bar? (see Zavh's comment) A QR code doesn't show the actual URL, at least as far as I recall.